# How to make Internet Explorer automatically login in a certain domain

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, authentication, iis, sharepoint-2010

In IE, when I want to access a SharePoint site, I'm asked for username/password (obviously).

Is there a way to make IE know that, when I access a domain XXX, it should use certain credentials? Even if I have to use a plugin.

I tried Windows Vault, but that doesn't seem to work with IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible for you and your domain users to do that without typing your user name or password !!!

This is very simple , only enough that you add your SharePoint URL (or Domain name like : *.domainname.local) in **Local Intranet** of IE. In **security** Tab

[image: Internet explorer configuration]

In my organization, we have active directory and all PCs joined to domain.

you can also do this with GPO through active directory [group policy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4936.adding-trusted-sites-to-internet-explorer-using-group-policy.aspx).

[Deploy IE "Trusted Sites" through Group Policy 2008](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/325-deploy-ie-trusted-sites-through-group-policy-2008)

[image: Deploy IE "Trusted Sites" through Group Policy 2008]

Comment: Very detailed reply, thanks. But adding the domain to "Trusted Sites" didn't cut it. I had to add it to "Intranet Sites".

Comment: ohhh thanks i know but ... mistake ... edit that ... i hope this is usefull

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've now accepted your answer (and deleted mine). Regards.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi On client's production environment there is already an entry with `*.doamin.com` in the IE "Local Intranet". And it is blocked by adding anything else to the "Local Intranet" section. Would auto login work for something such as `http://SERVER.dev.domain.dom`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php), however I'm not sure how well, or even how, it works with Internet Explorer (according to their site it does work). I've only used it with Chrome and Firefox before and it works great.

Comment: LastPass doesn't work for Windows Security. In IE, at least.

Comment: configure it by gpo or ie settings, set url as trusted site so single sign by domain user that login by windows, very easy and usefull.